# Миграция с SQLiteOpenHelper на Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Есть приложение написанное еще в 2017 году, которое работает с БД и использует `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Хочу переписать его и использовать обертку `Room`.

Но при этом хочу в одну из таблиц БД добавить новые колонки. Я правильно понимаю что нужно написать сначала миграцию, которая перенесет все данные из старой БД в новую, а потом еще одну миграцию, в которой я описываю добавление новых полей?

или это можно одной миграцией сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Room умеет работать с существующей БД.

Главное чтобы:

- Был правильно указан файл БД;
- Была правильно указана текущая версия БД;
- Модели соответствовали текущей структуре БД.

Тогда вероятнее всего переход будет без особых приключений.

После перехода уже используйте миграции.

P.S. Не так давно как раз переносил один из своих открытых проектов (первый релиз был в 2015 году) с `SQLiteOpenHelper` на Room (**не реклама!!!**). Можете посмотреть в [репозитории](https://github.com/Streletz/WeatherForecast) как сделано.

Comment: Спасибо посмотрю